# Spark Scala apply function on array of arrays element-wise

Tags: arrays, scala, apache-spark, multidimensional-array

Disclaimer: I'm VERY new to spark and scala. I am working on a document similarity project in Scala with Spark. I have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
+--------+--------------------+------------------+
|    text|            shingles|   hashed_shingles|
+--------+--------------------+------------------+
|  qwerty|[qwe, wer, ert, rty]|  [-4, -6, -1, -9]|
|qwerasfg|[qwe, wer, era, r...|[-4, -6, 6, -2, 2]|
+--------+--------------------+------------------+
```

Where I split the document text into shingles and computed a hash value for each one.

Imagine I have a `hash_function(integer, seed) -> integer`.
Now I want to apply `n` different hash functions of this form to the `hashed_shingles` arrays. I.e. obtain an array of `n` arrays such that each array is `hash_function(hashed_shingles, seed)` with seed from 1 to n.

I'm trying something like this, but I cannot get it to work:

```scala
val n = 3
df = df.withColumn("tmp", array_repeat($"hashed_shingles", n)) // Repeat minhashes
val minhash_expr = "transform(tmp,(x,i) -> hash_function(x, i))"
df = df.withColumn("tmp", expr(minhash_expr)) // Apply hash to each array
```

I know how to do it with a `udf`, but as I understand they are not optimized and I should try to avoid using them, so I try to do everything with `org.apache.spark.sql.functions`.

Any ideas on how to approach it without `udf`?

The `udf` which achieves the same goal is this:

```scala
// Family of hashing functions
class Hasher(seed: Int, max_val : Int, p : Int = 104729) {
  private val random_generator = new scala.util.Random(seed)
  val a = 1 + 2*random_generator.nextInt((p-2)/2)// a odd in [1, p-1]
  val b = 1 + random_generator.nextInt(p - 2) // b in [1, p-1]
  def getHash(x : Int) : Int = ((a*x + b) % p) % max_val
}

// Compute a list of minhashes from a list of hashers given a set of ids
class MinHasher(hashes : List[Hasher]) {
  def getMinHash(set : Seq[Int])(hasher : Hasher) : Int = set.map(hasher.getHash).min
  def getMinHashes(set: Seq[Int]) : Seq[Int] = hashes.map(getMinHash(set))
}

// Minhasher
val minhash_len = 100
val hashes = List.tabulate(minhash_len)(n => new Hasher(n, shingle_bins))
val minhasher = new MinHasher(hashes)

// Compute Minhashes
val minhasherUDF = udf[Seq[Int], Seq[Int]](minhasher.getMinHashes)
df = df.withColumn("minhashes", minhasherUDF('hashed_shingles))
```

Comment: It would help to understand the exact problem/requirement if you could provide the failed result/error along with expected result.

Comment: You are right, I added the udf which achieves the same goal.

Comment: Higher-order functions like `transform` (or `aggregate` like in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64666687/count-of-values-in-a-row-in-spark-dataframe-using-scala/64672866#64672866)) are for transforming data of complex type (e.g. Array) "element-wise" with a user-provided function.  In your use case, the entire Array is being used as a whole by your custom function, thus it isn't suitable to use `transform`.  I would go with your UDF approach.

Comment: Thank you, good to know.